# mac os: run as many scripts as cores in a sequence

Tags: r, multithreading, macos, batch-file

I have a script that reads parameters from a file (param.txt) and runs an R code (myRcode) for each combination of parameters (40 total). My mac has 8 cores so I want the script to run 8 jobs (when one finishes, starts another one, and so on). The script I currently have is this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

while read param1 param2 param3 
do

nohup R --no-save  > output_${param1}.txt << EOP &

source("MyRProgram.R");

myRcode(${param1},${param2},${param3})
EOP

echo "JobID = $! for parameters seed=${param1} n=${param2} submitted on `date`"
done < param.txt
exit
```

If I run ./Myscript  then all 40 jobs run simultaneously. I understand I could write 8 separate scripts (each reading parameters from different files) where inside the script each R code is separated by ";" - to make them run sequentially in each script. Is there is a better way that involves only one script?

Comment: Have a look at the R package [parallel](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf). It also offers load-balanced parallelization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash 

Rjob() {
    param1=$1
    param2=$2
    param3=$3

    echo "JobID = $! for parameters seed=${param1} n=${param2} submitted on `date`"

    R --no-save  > output_${param1}.txt << EOP

    source("MyRProgram.R");

    myRcode(${param1},${param2},${param3})
EOP
}
export -f Rjob

cat param.txt | parallel --colsep '\s' Rjob {1} {2} {3}
```

Comment: Thanks Ole. I will try your suggestion after I install GNU parallel.

Comment: Hi Ole. This is great! Two additional questions. Is it possible to choose how many cores I want to use ? Currently it seems to use all 8. What if I want to leave one free ? (use 7 only). Also, if I close the terminal the program stops. If there a way to run in the background so I can close to terminal and forget about it? Thanks again.

Comment: Use -P -1. Use tmux or screen. Walk through the tutorial to learn more: man parallel_tutorial

Comment: Will do that! Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I read the tutorial. It is a great tutorial btw. I then modified the last line in your script as follows "nohup cat param.txt | parallel -j6 --joblog /tmp/log2 --colsep '\s' Rjob {1} {2} {3} {4} &
cat /tmp/log2 > log.txt" The jobs run in the backgroupn and use 6 cores. But the log is empty because of the nohup in the previous line I guess. I can live without a log so I declare this a success. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The log entry is put in when the job is finished - not when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

No need, just use the fantastic GNU Parallel. Available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Try this to run 8 jobs at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Make a little job to do - nothing too tough!
echo sleep 5 > job
chmod +x job

# Now run those puppies
parallel -k -j 8 <<EOF
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job1 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job2 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job3 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job4 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job5 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job6 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job7 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job8 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job9 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job10 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job11 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job12 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job13 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job14 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job15 done'
  ./job; date +'%H:%M:%S Job16 done'
EOF
```

Or, if you dislike the idea of installing GNU Parallel, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=8
j=0
while read param1 param2 param3
do
   nohup R --no-save  > output_${param1}.txt << EOP &
   source("MyRProgram.R");
   myRcode(${param1},${param2},${param3})
   EOP

   ((j++))
   if [ $j -eq $MAX ]; then
     echo -n Pausing with $MAX processes...
     j=0
     wait
fi
done < param.txt
wait
```

By the way, you can get the number of cores on Mac with:

```
sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu
```

or

```
parallel --number-of-cores
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I tried your second suggestion and I see a problem with it. if one of the jobs takes more time than the other ones, then the script waits for all of them to finish before starting a new one. I would like the script to run a new job immediately after one is finished. Would your first suggestion have this property too?

Comment: That is the disadvantage of my second approach, but GNU Parallel does not have that problem - it just takes a little more effort to set up.

Comment: If I understand the idea of GNU parallel, I will have to write 40 lines (one line for every combination of parameters). Is that right? Second, is there a way to make the second approach wait in the background? If I close the terminal window then the script does not start new jobs after the first 8.

Comment: Go with @OleTang's suggestion - you are in excellent hands - he wrote GNU Parallel.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I just tried @OleTang's suggestion and it works very well.